# Dressing similarly at a Din Torah - When did this change and why?

Tags: history, clothing, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, beit-din-court

[Gemara Shevuos 31a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9721&st=&pgnum=63) says that if two people come to Bais Din one dressed in rags and the other dressed in expensive clothing, we make them dress similarly. [Sefer Hachinuch Mitzva 235](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46943&st=&pgnum=92) indicates that this is not done in his times. When did this stop and why?

Comment: It would be interesting to hear a contemporary dayan's take on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Choshen Mishpat - Shach 17:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9725&st=&pgnum=124) indicates in the name of the Raavan that it fell by the wayside since today no one wears a Uztila of 100 Mana.

Comment: Well apparently people have started again http://www.luxist.com/2009/02/24/50-000-suits-cut-from-worlds-most-expensive-cloth/ (1 Manah = 480 grams of silver; you do the math http://www.silvergrambars.com/calculator/ )

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam ([Sanhedrin 21:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=79&perek=21&halocha=5&hilite=), noted by Rabbi Chayim Dov Chavel in his edition of the Sefer HaChinuch — mitzvah **217** in his edition based on the first printing in Venice) says that the reason why is because we no longer have the ability to do the judgment perfectly.